# socket.io send data from server to client

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am trying to send some json object from the server side to the client side.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(1337);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var json = {
  var1: 1,
  var2: 2,
  var3: 3,
};

io.on('connection', function(json) {
  io.send('message', json);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

and on index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.0.js"></script>


<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
  
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

I keep getting this error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?
> EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1602487581123-0' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"socket.io": "^2.3.0",` for server side, change server side code to following:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var json = {
  var1: 1,
  var2: 2,
  var3: 3,
};

io.on('connection', function() {
  io.send('message', json);
});

http.listen(3000, () => console.log('HTTP server is listening on port 3000'));
```

For the CORS header, any origins being allowed by default.

And I recommend you use the latest version of `socket.io` for the client-side. You can use this [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io).

client side:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.1/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-AcZyhRP/tbAEsXCCGlziPun5iFvcSUpEz2jKkx0blkYKbxU81F+iq8FURwPn1sYFeksJ+sDDrI5XujsqSobWdQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
  
    socket.on('message', function(data, json) {
      console.log(data, json);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Create HTTP Server for client-side:

```
☁  64313396 [master] ⚡  http-server  -p 3001
Starting up http-server, serving ./public
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:3001
  http://172.31.160.227:3001
  http://10.23.128.81:3001
```

The output of browser console:

[image]